# Перенос системы из виртуального компьютера на реальный

Tags: debian, virtualbox

У меня на `virtualbox` есть компьютер, настроенный на `debian 7`. Хочу его перенести на стационарный компьютер. Возможно ли такое сделать? Если да, то может кто подскажет, в какую сторону смотреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Да, это возможно.
2. Чтобы это сделать, нужно перенести содержимое виртуального диска на физический - доустановить и настроить драйвера для физических у-в.